# How to export trained models from Kubeflow?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, onnx, kubeflow

I have a functional pipeline with Kubeflow that preprocess data / train the model / test it.
At the end of the pipeline, I would like to export the model with the ONNX format to use it in another application.

Is there any way to do that?